# Eloquent select rows with empty string or null value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, relationship

I have something like `$user->albums()->where('col', NULL)`, it works fine then I tried to extend it to empty strings with `$user->albums()->where('col', NULL)->or_where('col', '')` and it's not working.

Also I saw [on this post](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=19730) that I could use `where_null('col')` but it's not working and [it's not documented](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent). Any simple method to select where empty or NULL col

Comment: Just a tip for future users, the solution is whereNull('column'), as you can see in https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#unions

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try using [`orWhereNull`](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orWhereNull) for the second clause:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->where('col', '=', '')
        ->orWhereNull('col')
        ->get();
```

Or if you have multiple conditions in the query, you have to wrap the two in a closure:

```php
    $users = DB::table('users')
             ->where(function(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query) {
                $query->where('col', '')->orWhereNull('col');
            })
            ->where('col2','val2')
            ->get();
```

Comment: How would we change the where function incase if we have multiple conditions ?

Comment: @Nevermore Use a closure: `DB::table('users')->where(function($query) { $query->where(...)->orWhere(...)->orWhere(...); })->where(...)->where(...)->get();`. This will encapsulate the closure based conditions within parentheses in the rendered SQL.

Comment: Adding a model scope method can make using closures easier:
usage: 
$model->whereIsEmpty($column1)->whereIsEmpty($column2);
implementation:
public function scopeWhereIsEmpty($query, $column)
    {
        return $query->where(
            function ($query) use ($column) {
                $query->where($column, '')->orWhereNull($column);
            }
        );
    }

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
$user->albums()->whereRaw("NOT col > ''")
```

This way you can check both conditions at the same time

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->whereRaw('col = "" OR col IS NULL')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I always encourage to create queries with the main Laravel functions that are most used.
That's why you must have 2 things in mind:

- **algorithm**. key1 = value1 AND key2 = value2 OR key3 = value3. Be very carreful about precedence because in the way I exemplified there will be a main OR not an AND with OR inside
- **using where(), whereIn(), whereNull and closure instead of whereRaw()**. whereRaw is using more memory than any others I mentioned.

So, to resume your answer:

OR condition

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->where('col', '=', '')
        ->orWhere('col','=','')
        ->whereNull('col')
        ->get();
```

AND and OR condition

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->where(function($query) { $query->where('col','=','')->orWhere('col','=','')->whereNull('col'); })
->where('col','=','')
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

The below solution is tested on LARAVEL 9. Solution is to add to the App\Providers\AppServiceProvider this piece of code:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        ///...
        Builder::macro('whereNullOrEmpty', function ($field) {
            return $this->where(function ($query) use ($field) {
                return $query->where($field, '=', null)->orWhere($field, '=', '');
            });
        });

        Builder::macro('whereNotNullOrEmpty', function ($field) {
            return $this->where(function ($query) use ($field) {
                return $query->where($field, '<>', null)->where($field, '<>', '');
            });
        });
    }
    //...
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
if($nullOrEmpty){
    $builder->whereNullOrEmpty('col');
}else{
    $builder->whereNotNullOrEmpty('col');
}
```

You must call both commands:

```
where($field, '<>', null);
where($field, '<>', '');
```

because the MySql is handling empty strings and nulls different than a PHP

you also need to wrap those two commands with the closure to tell Eloquent to put generated code in parentheses and isolate MySql code:

```
(where col = null or where col = '')
```

Comment: Which Builder class is this

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder
\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder

Answer (score -5):

Not sure, but this might work:

```
$user->albums()->whereIn('col', [null,'']);
```

Comment: NULL cannot be compared using `=` operator, so this won't work. Also, the method's name is `whereIn`, rather than `where_in`. Could've tested it, instead of writing "not sure, but this might work"…

Comment: @jsphpl Your comment is correct of course, but it should be noted that if you run `whereIn('col', [null, ''])` on a `Collection` object rather than a query builder, it _will_ work. Example: `$user->albums->whereIn('col', [null,'']);`. Note the use of the magic relational property `albums`, which returns a collection, and not `albums()`, which returns a query builder instance.