# Laravel eloquent query WhereNotIn vs WhereNotNull

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a query where I want to check that a column `username` is both NOT NULL and NOT an empty string.

Which of these would be better?
Or are they equivalent?

```
->WhereNotNull('username')
->Where('username','!=','')
```

or

```
->WhereNotIn('username', [NULL, ''])
```

Comment: I doubt that `whereNotIn()` will work with `null`, but I've never tried it. Also, you might want to use a nested `where()` to handle this and prevent issues if you add more `where()` clauses: `->where(function($query){ $query->whereNotNull('username')->where('username', '!=', ''); }) ...`

Comment: the first one, for null value you need to use IS NULL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eloquent select rows with empty string or null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706874/eloquent-select-rows-with-empty-string-or-null-value)

Comment: Tim Lewis, yes after checking in MYSQL you cannot expect IN(NULL), etc., to work.  So using IS NOT NULL, followed by !='' would be the proper way to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best choice is:

```
->WhereNotNull('username')
->Where('username','!=','')
```

and I found this soulution but it is (like  N69S said in comment) is slower, I found it  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62271058/10573560):

```
->whereRaw('username>""')
```

this condition will exclude both null and empty values, but beside it slowness it is some kind of not clear.

`WhereNotIn` with an array with null will not work,
please note that laravel eloquent will translate this line:

```
->WhereNotIn('username', [NULL, ''])
```

to:

```
select * from `users` where `username` not in ('', '')
```

Comment: That answer was not selected as the right answer because the DB will need to string compare null fields which will make the query slower but sure, it will get the right results.